# Sync MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, triggers

Hi I know this question has been asked often, but I have a bit a different problem.
I have 2 Different Tables in 2 Databases ( One MYSQL One Microsoft SQL Server)

Now i want to map some entries to the other database. So far there is no problem, but i want to sync both of them..if possible in real time.

I have already tried SQL Triggers and searched some tools but none of them could help me.
I also tried SQL Server Studio to build a linkserver but this would just be one directional from MsSql to MySql.

does someone know a tool or any idea that could help me?

Comment: "if possible in real time" - is it a requirement or merely a nice to have?  what kind of latency is acceptable?

Comment: latency of ca 5-10 minutes is okay

Answer (score 0):

Given a delay of 5-10 minutes is acceptable, I'd go with the simplest thing you can get away with - rather than adding triggers, linked servers and the like.

Perhaps a scheduled task which runs every few minutes, and uses [SqlBulkCopy](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/122498/using-sqlbulkcopy-for-high-performance-inserts/) and [MySqlBulkCopy](https://code.google.com/p/mysqlbulkcopy/) to get the data transferred as efficiently as possible.